# Chrome OS Flex Kiosk - Website disable pinch

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode

Is there a way to disable and configure the Chrome website for Chrome OS Kiosk?

I have added the URL to the Chrome OS Kiosk device, so the device opens Chrome with that specific URL on startup. I would like to add a configuration for how Chrome should be opened, for example: `chrome.exe --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0`, but I can't find a way how to do it in Google Admin.

Is there some way how to do this from Admin?